# how to print when user link is active in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div>` that contains two  tags that reference to another `<div>`.

```
 <a onclick="Printelement('tester');" href"#">

 <div class="test">
     <a id="play" class="again activeLink" href="javascript:;"> First </a>
     <a id="play1" class="again" href="javascript:;"> First </a>
 </div>

 <div id="tester">
 </div>
```

How do I write a javascript to say when the user clicks on the first `<a>` link it prints whatever id is active?

Comment: You mean `PrintElement(document.querySelector(".activeLink").id)`?

Comment: the id holds all the information but there are two different id's within the same div and I want it to just print whatever id is showing

Comment: Bergi your code didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can print the Id of clicked anchor by binding the `click` event to them and use the following code.

```
$('.test a').on("click",function(){
   $('#tester').html($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fjxG4/2/)

Comment: this allows to use each as a button but I have 2 <a> tags within one div. So I need to be able to print the one that is active and not the one that isn't.